# zsh to iterate like in bash

Tags: bash, zsh

I recently switched from bash to zsh and not sure how to achieve this:

bash:

```
$ list='aaa
> bbb
> ccc
> ddd'

$ for i in $list; do echo $i-xxx; done
aaa-xxx
bbb-xxx
ccc-xxx
ddd-xxx
```

in zsh I get:

```
% list='aaa
quote> bbb
quote> ccc
quote> ddd'

% for i in $list; do echo $i-xxx; done
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd-xxx
```

how to force zsh to do this in the same way as bash?

Comment: You should use arrays in both shells instead of what you're trying.

Comment: The issue is that `zsh` does not, by default, perform word-splitting on an unquoted parameter expansion. There is an option you can set to make it do so, but using a string in that fashion isn't recommended in `bash`, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a parameter expansion flag to split the string at newlines:

```
for line in ${(f)list}; do ...
```

See http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags

Comment: You can also use `$=list` to split the string using characters from `$IFS` which includes newlines. That's closer to the behaviour of bash. `setopt shwordsplit` would also do the job.

Answer (score 5):

Most certainly consider using an array instead:

```
arraylist=(aaa bbb ccc ddd)
for i in "${arraylist[@]}"; do echo "$i-xxx"; done
```

You seem to want to iterate over lines in a variable, so you want to do:

```
while IFS= read -r i; do echo "$i-xxx"; done <<<"$list"
```

If you want to suffix each line with `-xxx` string, use `sed` instead:

```
sed 's/$/-xxx/' <<<"$line"
```

There's also `xargs`:

```
xargs -d'\n' -i echo {}-xxx <<<"$line"
```

If you want to iterate over *words* in a string and the words may be inside double quotes, I would go with `xargs`:

```
xargs -i echo {}-xxx <<<"$line"
```

If you want to iterate over *words* in a string without interpreting quotes, the way in other answer with `for i in $(echo $list)` is compatible with both zsh and bash

Comment: that echo is only example, I'd like to perform different activities on each line in for loop iterate on each of the line.. it might be curl, nc or any other command where line would the parameter..

Answer (score 0):

You have to split your string `list` on white space:

```
for i in ${(z)list}
do
   echo $i
done
```

Of course, the question is *why* you defined `list` as a scalar in the first place. Even in bash, it would perhaps make more sense to use it as array. In Zsh, an array would be (perhaps - depends on what else you want to do with it) even more convenient than a single string.