# Symlinks won't be created after switching from bash to zsh

Tags: bash, macos, shell, zsh

I made a shell script to automize my mac configuration. I have a loop which creates symlinks based on how many files are in this list e. g.:

```
files=".zshrc .gitconfig"

for file in ${files}; do
    echo "Creating symlink to $file in $homedir."
    ln -sf ${dir}/${file} ${homedir}/${file}
done
```

When I run my script in bash it works just fine. But if I run it in zsh it creates a symlink called ".zshrc .gitconfig". How can I iterate like in bash?

Comment: Add `setopt shwordsplit` to the top of your `zsh` script.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64632374/14234726) post answered my question. I needed to create an array to iterate through the list.. mb!

Comment: @dankoller112: Either do a `for file in ${(z)files}` (which would split the content of the variable on IFS, like in bash), or make `files` an array. The latter would be IMHO the cleaner solution, in both zsh and bash.